# Why is extending (splitting) list by word boundary not working?

Tags: python, split

I have two lists. I want to split each `name_list1` element (string) using the elements of `name_list2`

```
name_list1 = ['Peter Ham, FRE Marcus Miller, POR', 'Kyle Benham, KIT', 'Tory Net, WWQ']
name_list2 = ['Peter Ham, FRE', 'Marcus Miller, POR', 'Kyle Benham, KIT', 'Taylor Ben, KOO']
```

code

```
desired_list = []
pattern = f"\\b({'|'.join(name_list1)})\\b "
for i in name_list2:
    desired_list.extend(re.sub(pattern, "\\1:",i).split(':'))
```

here is how the list gets returned

```
undesired_list = ['Peter', 'Ham, FRE', 'Marcus', 'Miller, POR', 'Kyle', 'Benham, KIT', 'Tory', 'Net, WWQ', 'Taylor', 'Ben, KOO']
```

**how the list should be returned:**

```
desired_list = ['Peter Ham, FRE', 'Marcus Miller, POR', 'Kyle Benham, KIT', 'Tory Net, WWQ', 'Taylor Ben, KOO']
```

Consequently the resulting `desired_list` should have at least as many elements as `name_list2` has.

Comment: I'm getting the desired output.

Comment: with this example the elements of `name_list1` that are not in `name_list2` are not kept. I want the `desired_list` to contain `'Tory Net, WWQ'`. Any guess why on real data, the result  would look like in `undesired_list`?

Answer (score 1):

Because yor pattern use "|" (means OR). You don't need to use it. Without OR it works

```py
desired_list = []
pattern = f"\\b({' '.join(name_list1)})\\b "
for i in name_list2:
    desired_list.extend(re.sub(pattern, "\\1:",i).split(':'))

desired_list
Out[10]: ['Peter Ham, FRE', 'Marcus Miller, POR', 'Kyle Benham, KIT', 'Taylor Ben, KOO']
```

**EDIT**

You will get pattern `"\b(foo | bar)\b"`, wich will catch all words contains `"foo"` or `"bar"`. But you need catch only `"foo bar"`

Comment: If my answer was not only helpful for you, but solve your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking green mark